# Android Studio ambiguous method call for Object.toString

Tags: android-studio, tostring, ambiguous-call

Others have seen the "Ambiguous Method Call" error in Android Studio for

```
getClass()
```

But I'm seeing it for

```
Object.toString()
```

Has anyone else seen that?

The version of Android Studio I have is 0.8.6.

Comment: It's a compiler error or a lint error? Can you add a bit more context? Something like, class code and where you use it etc.

Comment: This is an IntelliJ bug.

Comment: Update: I am seeing others have the same issue here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-79680

Comment: I.don't think it's a big problem, your code still compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, to answer your actual question, yes I am seeing that, and I am running Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.14, and it is an Android Studio/IntelliJ bug, as mentioned before, so your code should be fine when you actually compile.  But, if you want it to stop underlining everything in red:

As you may notice on the issue of the `getClass()` call found at [Android Studio - Ambiguous method call getClass()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505973/android-studio-ambiguous-method-call-getclass?rq=1), you can cast the object in question to an `Object` to resolve it as such:

```
((Object) myObject).toString()
```

Alternatively, depending on the case you're dealing with, you may be able to rely on Java's included libraries implicitly* calling `toString()` on the object, as was the case with my code, where I was appending to a `StringBuffer`:

```
sb.append("Object's toString() returned: " + myObject);
```

Note: this will still work even if you didn't have the literal `String` object that I defined there, so this is also valid:

```
sb.append(myObject);
```

Or if you're simply printing to standard out,

```
System.out.println(myObject);
```

*As a side note, it is not actually being called implicitly, but rather many of Java's built-in classes have an overloaded method signature that accepts objects of type `Object`, which is then turned into a string via a call to `String.valueOf(myObject)` - see [How an object will call toString method implicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051481/how-an-object-will-call-tostring-method-implicitly) for more about this.