# Why this particular code generates "ambiguous method call" error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, itext, ambiguous

I use iText 5 in Android Studio to create a PDF document but I get an error:

[image]

I also tried

```
p.add((Phrase)c);
```

but I get same error :-(

How I can get rid of this error?

Comment: Is Phrase a sub-class of ArrayList? What does the `add` method look like?

Comment: try to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255420/what-is-an-ambiguous-type-error-in-java

Comment: Place there the minimized copy of your code (from which you remove EVERYTHING which is NOT needed to produce your error), including the `import` commands.

Comment: Try `((Phrase) p).add(c)`. If it works, I will put it as an answer :) now I just have a certain suspicion.

Comment: I stand corrected. In any case we need to see more of the code, and NOT as a screenshot but as actual code that anyone can copy/paste into their ID.

Comment: @DileepPatel: it is not the same case! Here he has "ambiguous **method call**" (the compiler cannot decide which **method** to use), whilst your linked question has "ambiguous **type**" (the compiler cannot decide which **type** to use: java.util.List vs. java.awt.List).

Answer (score 2):

In case when we use data binding, some java files are auto-generated
The problem was occured when a getter/setter has the same name with a function.
eg

- var newData
- fun getNewData()

in this case, in the generated java file, the variable's getter has the same name with the function => **getNewData**.

So simply you have to change variable name or fuction name

Answer (score 0):

"ambiguous" error comes up when u already have a file/varibale etc with same name.
for example when you make a project using entity framework , entity framework make class and dbcontext files for u. but if u add a class with same name as entity framework had made for u then this error comes up. check ur project/programe correctly and fully again... 
Hope its helpfull !!

and checkout this link for ur answer [Android Studio - Ambiguous method call getClass()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505973/android-studio-ambiguous-method-call-getclass)

Comment: I believe the OP does understand *what* the ambiguous type error is. He is asking *why* he has it in *this specific case*.

Comment: that is why i have given the link related to error because its is already answered by some1 earlier @HonzaZidek

Comment: But your explanation of the *ambiguous type* error does not belong here. It is completely confusing in the OP's particular context. The OP's problem most probably is **not** the class/variable with the same name!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reply - indeed I needed help regarding why 'ambiguous' appears in this context.
But now the problem is solved - this error does not appear anymore - but I don't know exactly why.
I did some Android Studio updates last week may this helped?

Thanks anyway!